# Java code coverage tools which support source line exclusions

Tags: java, code-coverage

I currently use [Clover](http://www.atlassian.com/software/clover/overview) to measure the code coverage of my Java code. One feature which I rely on is the ability to exclude arbitrary sections of code from coverage reports:

```
///CLOVER:OFF because this case is simpler to verify by code read
if (lFile.isFile() &&
    lFile.getName().endsWith(FILE_EXTN) &&
    !lFile.delete())
{
  throw new IOException("delete() failed for: " + lFile);
}
///CLOVER:ON
```

I find this kind of exclusion makes it much easier to focus on testing the interesting logic while still achieving 100% code coverage.

Are there any other Java code coverage tools (either free or paid) which support this kind of fine grained exclusion? Whole class or whole method exclusions aren't good enough.

NOTE: I am currently investigating adding something suitable to JaCoCo ([Issue #14](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco/issues/14)).

Comment: EMMA may add similar support in the future; cf. http://emma.sourceforge.net/faq.html *"A feature to allow EMMA users to mark arbitrary methods as excluded from coverage is being considered for future versions."*

Comment: Unfortunately that seems unlikely since the most recent EMMA release is from 2005. However, thanks for the link.

Comment: Don't see why this was closed. This question is objectively answerable.

Comment: I don't know of any offhand.  JaCoCo uses bytecode instrumentation at runtime, so using source code comments to control it would be a major change and why JaCoCo Issue #14 is more likely to be implemented with annotations.  That said, philosophically I discourage the practice that you're advocating because it puts the emphasis on having "100%" coverage when in fact that number is, frankly, pure fiction.  There are legitimate cases where code *should be unreachable* even by tests (e.g. false branches of _assert_ statements), but I strongly prefer to cover "uninteresting" logic by _testing_ it.

Comment: Just out of interest, why would you like to exclude something? Just lower your limit to 80% or whatever is useful.
To exclude something also can result in excluding important parts. You might have a part you think is not important and would include it, but one of your colleques thinks the opposite.

Comment: Not that I know of, as mentioned there are courser grained exclusions in Cobertura. The source code analyser PMD allows you to exclude analysis similar to Clover and it is useful especially when working on legacy code. I can see this feature will have a use in JaCoCo

Answer (score 1):

Followings are open source java code coverage tools. Those may help you
    [NoUnit](http://nounit.sourceforge.net/)
    [InsECT](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/insect)
    [Jester](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/insect)
    [JVMDI Code Coverage Analyser](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/jvmdi-code-coverage-analyser)
    [GroboCodeCoverage](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/grobocodecoverage)
    [jcoverage/gpl](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/jcoverage-gpl)
    [JBlanket](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/jblanket)
    [Cobertura](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/cobertura)
    [Coverlipse](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/coverlipse)
    [Hansel](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/hansel)
    [CodeCover](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/codecover)
    [EMMA](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/emma)
    [PIT](http://java-source.net/open-source/code-coverage/pit)

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the following all work well:

- In terms of closed-source: Clover
- In terms of open-source: Cobetura (but does not work with Java 7), EMMA